# Crear y seguir línea punteada en la pantalla

Tags: swift2, iphone

Tengo que imprimir líneas en la pantalla, ya sean números, letras o figuras, y el usuario debe marcarla con su dedo y si marca completa la línea entonces todo ok.

La idea es hacer algo como esto, pero en el iPhone o Pad, donde la niña debe seguir la marca de la línea con su dedo.
[image: Niña sigue la línea con el dedo]

O sea ¿Cómo hago para imprimir un número o líneas, que luego pueda ocupar para saber si el usuario la marco bien?

Estoy trabajando con SpriteKit y no se como hacerlo, ¿Alguien lo ha hecho que me pueda guiar por favor?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo? No se acaba de entender qué necesitas hacer. ¿A qué te refieres con "imprimir"? ¿y con "ocupar"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienas varias formas. Una de ellas sería dibujar `UIBezierPath` y compararlo con un patrón preestablecido punto por punto. Una vez evaluadas las distancias entre puntos, etc podrías saber si se ha acercado más o menos al dibujo original. Un ejemplo de como dibujar sería el siguiente:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1998968&seqNum=8

Por otro lado, existe una librería de reconocimiento de letras que seguramente la puedas adaptar para que reconozca otros patrones:
https://github.com/didierbrun/DBPathRecognizer

Comment: Justo se me había ocurrido lo que nombras de punto por punto, y más tu aporte del reconocimiento de letras esta muy muy bueno.Mil gracias !!!!!!!!!